# Prevent animation "spam" in Mouse enter/leave event

Tags: jquery

I am Hello, Once more i am Stuck on something. I was Creating a nevigation Menu for my Website and ran into the problem of having a Animation that easily spams itselt out just sliding in and out and in and out and in and out over and over again if the user moved the mouse back and forth, also there are some cases where switching the active window bugged the animation out. 
Now to my question, how can i make the animation only "play" once and not queue up infinite times. i tried using .clearQueue() but that didnt help it. Here is the Code

I dont want it to STOP the current animation. I want it to PREVENT more than one animation at once to be queued. So basically every animation plays until its done, and then only one close or open event can be executed, not infinite ones.

```
$(".navigation").delay(300).mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.navigation').delay(300).animate({ width: "285px" }, 200);

    $('body').delay(300).animate({ left: "285px" }, 200);

    $('.menubutton').delay(300).animate({ left: "300px" }, 200);

    $('.navigation p').delay(300).show(200);

});

$(".navigation").delay(300).mouseleave(function()
{
    $('.navigation').delay(300).animate({ width: "62px" }, 200);

    $('body').delay(300).animate({ left: "62px" }, 200);

    $('.menubutton').delay(300).animate({ left: "77px" }, 200);

    $('.navigation p').delay(300).hide(200);

});
```

here is the website the code is on:

http://www.klodel.com/cleandev/index.php?page=aboutpage

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yjkz3wyx/

Comment: Use the `stop()` method to clear the animation queue before calling a new one

Comment: Also, calling `delay(300)` before you define the event handler is a bad idea - I'm not event sure if it will work. Do it inside the event handler callback.

Comment: Sadly stop() didnt do what i meant. but i removed the delays, they where there for some testing thing, from an older version.

Comment: Is requirement for animations within events to proceed in sequential order ? i.e.g., `mouseenter : .navigation : width -> body : left -> .menubutton : left -> .navigation : show ` ? If possible , can create a jsfiddle with `html` , `css` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the method "stop", before the "animate".

```
$(".navigation").delay(300).mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.navigation').delay(300).stop().animate({ width: "285px" }, 200);

    $('body').delay(300).stop().stop().animate({ left: "285px" }, 200);

    $('.menubutton').delay(300).stop().animate({ left: "300px" }, 200);

    $('.navigation p').delay(300).stop().show(200);

});

$(".navigation").delay(300).mouseleave(function()
{
    $('.navigation').delay(300).stop().animate({ width: "62px" }, 200);

    $('body').delay(300).stop().animate({ left: "62px" }, 200);

    $('.menubutton').delay(300).stop().animate({ left: "77px" }, 200);

    $('.navigation p').delay(300).stop().hide(200);

});
```

Comment: Sadly stop didnt help, the animation STOPS now, when someone goes over it again, but its still spammable. i more wanted to force the animation to FINISH before it accepts a new input. Sorry if i made that sound unclear, i will edit the main question

Answer (score 0):

Piece below show perform animations in "sequence" , utilizing the `complete` callback of  [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) . Empties [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) on `mouseenter` , `mouseleave` ; to stop any "queued" animations that may be `inprogress` at either `event`

Try

```
$(".navigation").mouseenter(function() {
    // empty `queue` before
    // starting `mouseenter` animation
    $('.navigation').queue("fx", [])
    .animate({ width: "285px" }, 200
    , function() {
      $('body').animate({ left: "285px" }, 200
      , function() {
        $('.menubutton').animate({ left: "300px" }, 200
        , function() {
          $('.navigation p').delay(300).show(200);
        })              
      });
    })
});

$(".navigation").mouseleave(function() {
    // empty `queue` before
    // starting `mouseleave` animation
    $('.navigation').queue("fx", [])
    .animate({ width: "62px" }, 200
    , function() {
      $('body').animate({ left: "62px" }, 200
      , function() {
        $('.menubutton').delay(300).animate({ left: "77px" }, 200
        , function() {
          $('.navigation p').delay(300).hide(200);
        })
      }}
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/yjkz3wyx/1/